# Not all files in mounted directory on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, files, mount, windows

I have a linux serwer with Vesta instaled and I need to show pdf files on webservice from windows based file serwer.

I use this command to mount files from windows:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=guest,password=,uid=apache,gid=apache //192.168.0.xxx/xxx/PDFARCHIWUM /home/admin/web/xxx.mydomain.xxx/public_html/archiwum_pdf/
```

It works fine and fast except not all files are mounted. On windows on example directory there is 2393 files in directory while in linux I find only 1690 (I saw some files are missing and the run this: `ls | wc -l`).

Example file that was missing:
`/home/admin/web/xxx.mydomain.xxx/public_html/archiwum_pdf/2019/20190913/XXXX_20190913_942_A_1_34_OP.pdf`

Unmounting with: `umount -a -t cifs -l` did not help
These are all same types of files: pdf

Comment: Does your guest account have access to all those files?

Comment: Should have. They are created the same way, but from different locations and stored in one bigder server (same aps, same everything.... but you might be right - I will try to pursue this). Any advice how? (all are windows machines)

Comment: I have created the mount even with root privilages - same thing.

Comment: I meant permissions on the windows side, not Linux side

Comment: The permissions on windows side were ok too (all users had read and execute), for now my co worker set up share on linux, and it's working fine. Propably we will stay on linux. Thank you for your help. Is there any thoer way to mound windows share then cifs (with windows gate respository instaled)? I have came acroos information that there was/there is a bug that is creating sth like what I experience now.